# Return nodes with same name in xml2

Tags: r, xml, xml2

I have an xml file where there are many nodes with the same name. The names of the nodes are out of my control. Is there a way to access the values of each of the nodes with the same name, not just the first.

In the help file for `xml_child()` it states that you can use the `search` parameter to "specify the name of the child node to return. If there are multiple child nodes with the same name, the first will be returned."

Unfortunately, I also don't always know the position of the nodes with the same name, so I also can't use a numeric value for the search parameter.

For example:

```
# similar example provided in the xml2 documentation
x <- read_xml("<foo> a <d>e1</d> <d>e2</d> </foo>")

# this gives expected output from the first child node named "d"
xml_child(x, "d") %>% xml_contents()

# this gives me expected output from second child node with name "d"
# but I don't always know the position of this node
xml_child(x, 2) %>% xml_contents()
```

So is there a way for me to access the value of the second node with the name "d"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `[]` to specify which node index you want. You can get the second `d` node with

```
xml_child(x, "d[2]") %>% xml_contents()
```

This is an [xpath predicate](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp)